# Wrong background in iOS app (part 2)

Tags: bug, ios-app

[The old bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285277/339911) has been tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but it seems to have happened again in the new version of the app:

> [image: question background]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)